# Why does the top guy win the hand?

Tags: poker-theory, cash-game, flush

[image]Hello guys,
I have a question regarding the following poker game i played recently. I lost again the guy on the top despite both of us having a flush of clubs and me even having the higher flush compared to his. He won the pot and i really dont get it why. Maybe you can help me out. Screenshot below

Comment: You might have accidentally tapped fold instead of call without knowing it.

Answer (score 2):

You're hand is definitely higher than his. If you are sure that he won the hand, then it is a mistake and you should have won.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the other guy won, because he has six in total and you have five of clubs?

If that is not a valid reason, then yes, the game is programmed wrong.

Comment: Hey @andylib93, thanks for contributing and adding an answer. The second part of your answer is correct here, Texas Hold'em is a 5 card game so the first question/part of your answer isn't correct. Just commenting as some feedback for you!

Comment: Oh I see, so you can't even count six cards - no matter the suit. Thank you!